# is it possible to combine radiobutton and submit in 1 submit button?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a radiobutton and the value gets submitted with a submitbutton. I only want a submitbutton that submits the value when clicked. So instead of a radiobutton and a submitbutton separate I want a radiobutton and submit button rolled into 1.

This is my code:

```
{foreach item=item key=key from=$memberships}
<input type="radio" type="hidden" name="membership" value="{$key}" checked="checked"/>
{$item}
{/foreach}
<input class="button" type="submit" value="{lang mkey='continue'} --&gt;"/>
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

replace the radiobutton and submit button with just a submit button.

```
<button type="submit" name="membership" value="{$key}">{$item}</button>
```

Would it be possible and how to do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want the submit to do and look like? Do you want it to be just a button that does things behind the scenes? Or do you want radio buttons to submit?

Comment: Re-read your question.  It doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Hi rewrote the question hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have

```
<input type="radio" type="hidden" name="membership" value="{$key}" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.submit();"/>
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" type="hidden" name="membership" id="membership" value="{$key}">
<button type="submit" name="membership" onclick="document.formname.membership.value={$key}; return true;">{lang mkey='continue'}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small image that looks like a radio button and map that as your submit button. This would give the illusion of having a radio button but when a user clicks it your form would submit.

If you really want to jazz it up, have a second image like a selected radio button and show that with something like an onClick() event.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. The onclick solution is working fine and I will use your answer to style it further with a image.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't have a submit button, and then use an onclick event for the radio button that submits the form.